# Let $f(x) = \frac{3x^2 - 10x - 25}{x + 1}$ and $g(x) = \frac{3x^2 - 10x - 25}{3x^2 + 11x + 10}$...

Tags: functions

Let $f(x) = \frac{3x^2 - 10x - 25}{x + 1}$ and $g(x) = \frac{3x^2 - 10x - 25}{3x^2 + 11x + 10}$. Find the sum of all real numbers that are not in the domain of $f(g(x))$.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Hint: Substitute value of g(x) in place of x in equation of f(x) and then check condition for which denominator won't be 0. After finding all possible values of x for which denominator is 0 add them up. If you aren't still clear then I'll write down the answer. But tell me after trying first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of $f(g(x))$ is certainly a subset of the domain of $g$, which is determined by $3x^2+11x+10\ne0$, which excludes two values: can you find them?

However, $f$ is not defined at $-1$, so we need to exclude also all values of $x$ for which $g(x)=-1$, which becomes
$$
3x^2-10x-25=-3x^2-11x-10
$$
Can you solve the equation?

Answer (score 1):

Well first simplify $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

$$f(x)={{3x^2-10x-25}\over{x+1}}={{(3x+5)(x-5)}\over(x+1)}$$

$$g(x)={{3x^2-10x-25}\over{3x^2+11x+10}}={{(3x+5)(x-5)}\over{(3x+5)(x+2)}}={{x-5}\over{x+2}}$$

Now,

$$f(g(x))=(3({{x-5}\over{x+2}})+5)(({{x-5}\over{x+2}}-5)({{x+2}\over{2x-3}})$$

Now to find the numbers which are not in the domain of $f(g(x))$ we just need to determine what [real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) would make the denominators of the fractions equal to zero if substituted in place of $x$

This gives the set $\left\{ -2, -{5\over{3}},{3\over{2}} \right \}$

$\therefore$ the sum of all real numbers not in the set of $f(g(x))$  is $-2-{5\over{3}}+{3\over{2}}=-{13\over{6}}$

Hope this is insightful.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think you missed -5/3 though :P

Comment: @QuantumPizza doesn't $(3x+5)\over{(3x+5}$ cancel in $g(x)$ so $-5\over{3}$ is within $f(g(x))$?

Comment: @ Ploni Almoni No, it's actually not within $f(g(x))$.